# Lua executes python script in background

Tags: python, security, lua, telegram

I have problem to run script in background.

I have Lua file:

```
function on_msg_receive (msg)
  if (msg.text=="Alarmon") then
    send_msg (msg.from.print_name, 'Sensor ON!', ok_cb, false)
    io.popen('/home/pi/led.py')
  end
end
```

An Python file (for tests):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
pinn=4
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(pinn,GPIO.OUT)
print "LED on"
GPIO.output(pinn,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(5)
print "LED off"
GPIO.output(pinn,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

After execute it i get:

```
/home/pi/led.py: 1: /home/pi/led.py: import: not found
/home/pi/led.py: 2: /home/pi/led.py: import: not found
/home/pi/led.py: 4: /home/pi/led.py: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Its Lua file to work with Telegram. I run message "Alarmon" and then it works untill error pops out.
I think there is problem that `io.popen` dont run `led.py` in python.
How to change it?

Comment: Change the call to `io.popen('python /home/pi/led.py')`

Comment: Oh it works! So simple.... Do You know how to terminate this popen file?

Comment: Nope. google it.

Comment: I did and always did it at first. I have found io.close(f) but problem is, i need this command in other if statement. One on msg="Alarmon" works, but on msg="Alarmoff" i cant find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you only provide io.popen a path to a Python script.

```
function on_msg_receive (msg)
  if (msg.text=="Alarmon") then
    send_msg (msg.from.print_name, 'Sensor ON!', ok_cb, false)
    io.popen('/home/pi/led.py')
  end
```

Your computer doesn't know what to do with it.

From the [Lua 5.3 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-io.popen):

> **io.popen (prog [, mode])**
>
> This function is system dependent and is not available on all
>   platforms.
>
> Starts program prog in a separated process and returns a file handle
>   that you can use to read data from this program (if mode is "r", the
>   default) or to write data to this program (if mode is "w").

So in order to make it work you have to actually start a program, which in your case is the Python interpreter.
Given that you have the Python interpreter's location in your PATH system variable this should work:

```
io.popen('Python')
```

And as you want the interpeter to run a script you also provide the script's path as argument.

```
io.popen('Python /home/pi/led.py')
```

The same you would enter into the command line interface...

If you're not planning to use any in or output to or from  the program you can simply use:

```
os.execute('Python /home/pi/led.py')
```

instead

Comment: Thank You for this explanation. Clears all. Ok, so i can use io.popen (os. execute blokcs my actual program), but how to terminate started program in another "If" statement?

Comment: @eonmax Lua doesn't have a command for this. you could execute os.execute("taskkill /im python.exe") for example